# Let $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a Lebesgue measurable function in $L^2$. Show $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ satisfies $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\frac 12$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a Lebesgue measurable function that is in $L^2$. Show $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ satisfies $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\frac 12$.

Here's what I have so far.

$f\in L^2 \Rightarrow (\int (|f|)^2d\lambda )^\frac12 \lt \infty \Rightarrow |f| \lt \infty$ a.e.

$|F(x)-F(y)|=|\int_0^xf(t)dt - \int_0^yf(t)dt|=|\int_y^xf(t)dt|=|\int f\mathbf 1_{[y,x]} d\lambda| \leq \int |f\mathbf 1_{[y,x]}| d\lambda \leq sup_{t \in [y,x]}f(t) |x-y|$

I'm not entirely sure where i've gone wrong, can someone please give me some pointers on how to get the $\frac 12$ in the exponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, use $\text{H}\ddot{o}\text{lder}$'s Inequality: $f(x) = 1 f(x)$. Assume (WLOG) $y > x$.

$$\int_x^y |f(t)|\,\text{d}t \leq \left(\int_x^y |f(t)|^2\,\text{d}t \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_x^y |1|\,\text{d}t \right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: I see, so I get $||f||_2 ||\mathbf 1_{[y,x]}||_2 \leq (sup_{t \in [y,x]}f(t))^\frac 12 |x-y|^\frac 12$

Comment: @Henry No! First, you're leaving out one of the integrals. But even if your calculations were correct, $\sup|f(t)|$ may be infinite! You want a finite $C$. Look at the answer again and see what other $C$ works here...

Comment: @Henry (Also your $C$ depends on $x$ and $y$; it's supposed to be independent of $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: Oh does $f \in L^2$ imply it's finite instead without the need for sup.

Comment: @Henry Imply _what's_ finite? You're saying we can let $C$ be what?

Comment: $f\in L^2 \Rightarrow ||f||_2 =(\int (|f|)^2d\lambda )^\frac12 = C \lt \infty$?

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Use Cauchy Swartz inequality and that $f\in L^2$